# Codeigniter redirects best approach to choose

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

In the same controller i have found there are two ways to redirect.

```
Class Home extends mY_Controller{

    public $view;
    public $redirect;
    function first_method
    {
        $this->view =   FALSE;
        //   $this->second_method();
        //   redirect('Home/second_method');            
    }

    function second_method()
    {
        echo 'Second one';
    }       
}
```

I want to know which is the best approach also 
i have a redirect method in the my_controller 
if certain conditions do not match redirect the user using redirect variable 
just for simplicity i am posting this

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    protected $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _remap($method, $parameters)
    {
        if($this->view === FALSE)
        {
            redirect($this->redirect);
        }else{
            $this->load->view('my_view');
        }   

    }
}
```

Using the first method i am unable to access the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `redirect()` as it's easy to change HTTP response code later, if you will need it, as well as making some of them to be `refresh` type.

You can always override the helper if you'll find it necessary to change all your redirects later and you'll even have ability to add some logic to them.